# React Bootstrap component (Form.Control) OnChange event listener doesn't fire when select all text and delete

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using **Form.Control** in form , and when changing the input , I use onChange event  listener, to handle the change
as in this snapshot :

```
<Form.Control
      className="form-control"
      type="text"
      id={props.id}
      defaultValue={props.placeholder}
      onChange={(e) => {
        updateInput(e);
      }}
></Form.Control>
```

all changes work fine , adding chars , deleting ,,etc , 
**But** when => **Select ALL text and hit backspace , onChange event Listener , isn't fired !** 
ps : selecting part of the text and deleting it , fires the onChange .

Comment: ```onChange={(e) => {
    updateInput(e.target.value);
}}```

Answer (score 2):

Ok , I solved this issue by , adding onSelect event listener, and called same function triggered from onChange , as in this snapshot  :

```
<Form.Control
          className="form-control"
          type="text"
          id={props.id}
          defaultValue={props.placeholder}
          onChange={(e) => {
            updateInput(e);
          }}
          onSelect={(e) => {
            updateInput(e);
          }}
></Form.Control>
```

however , I believe something is wrong with onChange event listener and this is just a workaround .

Comment: [onChange of Form.Control](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#form-control-props) should work. Can you provide minimal & complete code example of the issue?

Comment: @AjeetShah onChange doesn't work alone when selecting all text and pressing delete WHEN there is a `defaultValue`, otherwise it works. The callback is not fired. Adding onSelect callback fixes the issue but as the author says it's a workaround and should work with onChange only